# Java collect with grouping and mapping for `set`, but need an empty set if all values are `null`

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

In my Java 11 application, I want to get Product Updates from a repository. One Product Update has a `updateId` and a list of `productIds` to update.

- If there are no product numbers that should be updated for update with `updateId = X`, I still want to write to another table that I've processed the update `X`; `updateStatusRepository.setStatusProcessing(updateId)` and `updateStatusRepository.setStatusProcessed(updateId)` should still be called for this `updateId`.
- If there are product updates present, they should be processed in the `ProductProcessingService`.

For now, the `groupingBy` and `mapping` give me a Set with a `null` entry instead of an empty set, which is why I later remove all `null` Product IDs.

```
List<ProductUpdate> productUpdateList = updateStatusRepository.getProductUpdates();
Map<String, Set<String>> productUpdateMap = productUpdateList
          .stream()
          .collect(
              Collectors.groupingBy(
                  ProductUpdate::getUpdateId,
                  Collectors.mapping(ProductUpdate::getProductNo, Collectors.toSet())));

productUpdateMap.forEach(
          (updateId, productIds) -> {
        try {
          updateStatusRepository.setStatusProcessing(updateId);
          productIds.remove(null);
          if(!productIds.isEmpty()) {
            productProcessingService.performProcessing(Lists.newArrayList(productIds));
          }
          updateStatusRepository.setStatusProcessed(updateId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              //
        }
});
```

I'd prefer if it were possible to use `mapping` in such a way that it delivers an empty Set directly if all values are `null`.

Is there a way to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`Collectors.filtering`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#filtering(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> productUpdateMap = productUpdateList
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               ProductUpdate::getVersionId,
               Collectors.mapping(ProductUpdate::getProductNo, 
                                  Collectors.filtering(Objects::nonNull, 
                                                       Collectors.toSet()))));
```

I think `Collectors.filtering` fits your exact use case: it will filter out `null` product numbers, leaving an empty set if all product numbers happen to be `null`.

---

**EDIT:** Note that in this case, using `Collectors.filtering` as a downstream collector is not the same as using `Stream.filter` before collecting. In the latter case, if we filtered out elements with a `null` product number before collecting, we might end up with a map without entries for some version id, i.e. in case all product numbers are `null` for one specific version id.

From `Collectors.filtering` docs:

> **API Note:**
>
> The `filtering()` collectors are most useful when used in a multi-level reduction, such as downstream of a `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy`. For example, given a stream of `Employee`, to accumulate the employees in each department that have a salary above a certain threshold:
>
> ```
> Map<Department, Set<Employee>> wellPaidEmployeesByDepartment
>   = employees.stream().collect(
>     groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
>                filtering(e -> e.getSalary() > 2000,
>                          toSet())));
> ```
>
> A filtering collector differs from a stream's `filter()` operation. In this example, suppose there are no employees whose salary is above the threshold in some department. Using a filtering collector as shown above would result in a mapping from that department to an empty `Set`. If a stream `filter()` operation were done instead, there would be no mapping for that department at all.

---

**EDIT 2:** I think it's worth mentioning the alternative proposed by @Holger in the comments:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> productUpdateMap = productUpdateList
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               ProductUpdate::getVersionId, 
               Collectors.flatMapping(pu -> Stream.ofNullable(pu.getProductNo()), 
                                      Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Or `productUpdateList .stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( ProductUpdate::getVersionId, Collectors.flatMapping(pu-> Stream.ofNullable(pu.getProductNo()), Collectors.toSet())))`